# How to indicate a major code change in Google Analytics timeline

Tags: google-analytics

I recently made a change to a WordPress site I maintain, and I expect this change to dramatically improve page load time. So far, it seems to be working.

However, in the coming weeks and months I would like to be able to look back in Google Analytics and see an indication of the exact date I made the change, so that I'll be able to see that, if my page load times improved, whether that improvement correlated with the change I made. See this screen shot for an idea of what I'm talking about:

[image: Screen shot of what I'd like to accomplish in GA]

I could just write down the date that I made the change somewhere, but it'll be easier to keep track of and not lose if it could somehow be stored right in GA itself. Also, there are likely other performance improvements coming up, and I'd like to do the same for them, so it's not just a one-off problem.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google Annotation** is what you need. You can click on the "Down arrow"(below the Timeline) button and it will expand like the screenshot below.

Annotation will be marked differently(as highlighted in the screenshot) so that you can know while looking at your Anlaytics timeline if you have a change in the Traffic.

[image: Google Analytics Annotation]